# How to embed social media post with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, embed

I have been trying to embed videos and post from facebook,twitter and instagram into my flutter application but i was not able to do so.

1. I have tried this [social_embed_webview](https://pub.dev/packages/social_embed_webview)  but it does not work fine especially the facebook embed it always throws an error saying the post might have been deleted.
2. I have also tried using this [flutter_html_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html_view/versions) but it was old because the last changes was done 3 years ago and with flutter a lot has changed so the dependences is not compactible with my project dependences

Comment: It does not work well with Facebook posts